# My IP address was hacked by Trojan Tiny Banker

Tags: malware

I was using a unsecured website to watch movies and my windows 10 alert went off saying my registration code had been blocked or something to that nature and to call1(888)2521262 .. tech support.. they basically told me I can’t change my IP address and the only way to fix the issue it to pay 500 for firewall protection or they can steal all the personal information linked /used on this IP address.. I’m not the least bit computer savvy so I don’t know what I’m doing . Please someone help me.. I wanna know if there’s a way to change my IP address  and what to do from here

Comment: Your "IP address" wasn't hacked. That's not how the Internet works. Most likely your questionable legality site runs ads and your got a browser hijack that made it look like you got hacked. You call the support number and they tell you bad things will happen if you don't pay up. Common scam

Comment: Well, you were savvy enough to ask here. Now hang up the phone, don't pay them any money, and in the future don't call random phone numbers that appear in ads or email. And don't use that website anymore.

Answer (score 2):

As people answered in the comments, this is a comon scam, the basic rules when browsing streaming sites are :

- Have your computer and browser always updated so you are less vulnerable to attacks
- Do not download anything, and if you did accidentally, do not open/execute the downloaded file
- If your browser is unresponsive and tells you the police/aliens/hackers/Microsoft Support team has hijacked your browser and that you need to call them and/or pay them money : don't comply, try to close your browser, and if it doesnt work, shut down the computer
- Do not install unknown browser extensions
- Have a copy of every important file in a secure location (cloud storage account, gmail, external hard drive) so that if you ever need to do a complete restoration of your computer, you just lose a bit of time
- Do not use your administrator account for casual activities like browsing the internet

To answer your question, you can't decide to change your IP Address unless your ISP allows you to do it, but that's not a problem since the people you talked to on the phone can't steal all your personal information with just your IP Address.

Now if you installed any "diagnostic" software they asked you to install during the call, your computer is compromised and you will probably need a fresh windows install to get rid of it.

If you did not install or execute anything shady, you should not worry. As proposed in the comments, you might want to still perform a malware scan.

Comment: Performing an malware scan would probably be a good idea anyways. Note also that even if it's only in-browser, auto-session restore may bring the user back to the same issue. Launching the browser in safe mode or its equivalent would then be needed to get rid of the problem.